# Convert stored procedure to a table-valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, stored-procedures

Below is a a stored procedure written a long time ago. Is it possible to convert this into a table-valued function? Alternatively is there a better method or approach which can be considered to replace it?

The objective is "As a reporting analyst, I want to be able to report on Ward Stays at a configurable census point over a configurable number of days."

If I enter a `StartDate` (Inc `DateTime` behind the scenes, just bad naming) of 01/01/2023 and `EndDate` (same, is actually a datetime) of 01/01/2023 and a time of 2pm the resultant dataset would calculate all those ACTIVE between those dates.

Example

- I arrive at 14:01pm on 01/01/2023 therefore would NOT be included (2pm census date I was there)
- I arrive at 13:59pm on 01/01/2023 therefore would be included  (2pm census date I was not there yet)

This might not be specific to a given day, so for example I may want to see a weeks (7 days) worth, so if I again arrive onday 1 and am still there after a week, the loop through would record be being as active for the census time every day eg @2pm on 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07.

Ultimately the goal is to see a dataset of all those who are active at a specific time over a configurable period.

As I say, below does the job currently but the objects used are no longer available to having to replicate using the object we now use and this has been done, but I question can this be done better using a different approach like a table-valued function.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HEY_spWardStaysAtCensusDate]
    @StartDate DATE,
    @EndDate DATE,
    @CensusTime TIME
AS
    DECLARE @NoOfDays INT,
            @LoopCounter INT,
            @CensusDate DATETIME

    SELECT 
        @NoOfDays = DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#WardStays') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #WardStays
    END

    CREATE TABLE #WardStays 
    (
        WARD_STAY_UNIQUE_ID INT NOT NULL,
        CENSUS_DATE_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL,
        LOCAL_PATIENT_NUMBER VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        WARD_CODE VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        WARD_START_DATE_TIME DATETIME NULL,
        WARD_END_DATE_TIME DATETIME NULL,
        TRUST_SITE_LOCAL VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        TRUST_SITE_NATIONAL VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        WARD_STAY_COUNTER INT NULL
    )

    SELECT @LoopCounter = 1
  
    WHILE @LoopCounter <= @NoOfDays
    BEGIN
        SET @CensusDate = DATEADD(DAY, @LoopCounter - 1, @StartDate) + CAST(@CensusTime AS DATETIME)

        INSERT INTO #WardStays (WARD_STAY_UNIQUE_ID, CENSUS_DATE_TIME, LOCAL_PATIENT_NUMBER, WARD_CODE, WARD_START_DATE_TIME,
WARD_END_DATE_TIME, TRUST_SITE_LOCAL, TRUST_SITE_NATIONAL, WARD_STAY_COUNTER)
            SELECT 
                IPWardStayID, @CensusDate, HEYNo, WardCode, 
                WardStartDateTime, WardEndDateTime, HospitalCode,
                HospitalNatCode, 1
            FROM 
                HealthBI_Views.dbo.IP_WARD_STAY
            WHERE 
                WardStartDateTime <= @CensusDate
                AND (WardEndDateTime >= @CensusDate OR WardEndDateTime IS NULL)

        SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter + 1
    END

    SELECT 
        WARD_STAY_UNIQUE_ID, CENSUS_DATE_TIME, 
        LOCAL_PATIENT_NUMBER, WARD_CODE, 
        WARD_START_DATE_TIME, WARD_END_DATE_TIME, 
        TRUST_SITE_LOCAL, TRUST_SITE_NATIONAL, WARD_STAY_COUNTER
    FROM 
        #WardStays
```

Comment: Why don't you have a go and then ask a question if you get stuck? It a bit much expecting someone here to do it all for you

Comment: And if you are looking for a way to remove the loop you need to provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: It's pretty simple conversion, but you need to replace a temporary table with a table variable or if you're writing table value function, just populate that embedded return table variable with your data

Comment: Thanks I did have a stab at it, and have something I think may worth, just always ask in case there are alternatives to my approach and can assess varying methods on performance in addition to re-writing

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this quite easily. All you need to do is replace the loop with a call to `GENERATE_SERIES`. In older versions of SQL Server, you can use an inline numbers function such as [one of these](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1).

Then you calculate the `datetime` value inside an `APPLY` and finally `JOIN` the main table to it.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.HEY_spWardStaysAtCensusDate (
    @StartDate DATE,
    @EndDate DATE,
    @CensusTime TIME
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

SELECT 
  WARD_STAY_UNIQUE_ID  = IPWardStayID,
  v.CENSUS_DATE_TIME,
  LOCAL_PATIENT_NUMBER = HEYNo,
  WARD_CODE            = WardCode, 
  WARD_START_DATE_TIME = WardStartDateTime,
  WARD_END_DATE_TIME   = WardEndDateTime,
  TRUST_SITE_LOCAL     = HospitalCode,
  TRUST_SITE_NATIONAL  = HospitalNatCode,
  WARD_STAY_COUNTER    = 1
FROM
    GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)) g
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CENSUS_DATE_TIME =
      DATEADD(day, g.value, @StartDate) + CAST(@CensusTime AS DATETIME)
) v
JOIN
    HealthBI_Views.dbo.IP_WARD_STAY
    ON WardStartDateTime <= v.CENSUS_DATE_TIME 
   AND (WardEndDateTime >= v.CENSUS_DATE_TIME OR WardEndDateTime IS NULL)
;
```

Comment: I wish we had 2022 version, we are only up to 2019